# I am getting confused on this one as to how is this funtion call working

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

`fptr` is a function pointer, and even if I pass `fptr` instead of `threadFunc` in `pthread_create()` it still works.

Shouldn't it be `*fptr` that must be passed instead of just `fptr`? How is it working with `fptr` instead of `*fptr`?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <thread>
 using namespace std;
 void* threadFunc(void *arg){
   cout<<"Thread FUnction\n";
   pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

 int main(){
   pthread_t my_thread;
   void* (*fptr)(void*);
   fptr=threadFunc;
   int ret = pthread_create(&my_thread,NULL,fptr,NULL);

   if(ret){
     printf("Error creating thread\n" );
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);

 }
```